# Protractor starts Firefox but doesn't run any tests

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Problem is the web app I'm testing is behind 2 basic auths and requires a proxy.

I wanted to pass the two basic auths by adding AutoAuth addon in a FireFox profile and setting up that profile to load in my conf.js everytime I call a new instance of firefox.
Problem is FF starts and does not execute anything -> just stays blank.

My conf.js

```
    exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['./testScripts/*.js'],
  capabilities: {
   'browserName': 'firefox',
    firefoxPath: 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe',
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
   'args': ["-profile","C:/Users/QA/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/vp04m5l2.fireFoxTestAcc"]
    }
},
```

As soon as I add marionette: false, or I disable the firefox profile the code in my spec starts executing. Tested with directconnect true&false.

> Protractor Version 5.3.0
>  Firefox Version : 59.0b8
>  geckodriver
>
> - v0.19.1
>    NPM - 5.6.0

Comment: Thanks for this question..I m also facing the same issue when using "moz:firefoxOptions" for the profile as I require "modify headers" in my application.